# ArrayList to Json

Tags: jquery, json, servlets, jboss, arraylist

Receive result from query in SessionBean

```
public List getUserTransaction(User user, Balancestatus status) {
return em.createNamedQuery("Balance.findLastFiveTransaction").setParameter("user", user).setParameter("status", status).getResultList();
```

My query

```
select b from Balance b join b.typecategory t where b.user = :user and b.typecategory = t and b.status = :status
```

Getting data in servlet and passed to Json

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 
user = userHandler.userCheck("mail@mail.com");
List<Balance> userTransaction = balance.getUserTransaction(user, outStatus);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(userTransaction);
 
out.write(json);
```

Try parse using JQuery and output in console

```
.............
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
console.log(element);
});
..............
```

and get the error

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
> [Break On This Error]
>
> typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj );

My Json from ArrayList to Json

> [{"id":"7","description":"evil data
> show","sum":666.00,"category":{"id":"1","name":"Wallet"},"typecategory":{"id":"4","name":"Home"},"user":{"id":"1","created":"Jun
> 5, 2013 1:44:45
> PM","email":"mail@mail.com","pass":"mail","updated":"Jun 5, 2013
> 1:44:45 PM"},"status":{"id":"2","statusName":"out"}}
> ...........]

How correct passed ArrayList to Json? Use JBoss AS 7.1

Comment: Found solution need parse JSon and delete space. Later add full correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution

> **$.parseJSON(data.trim());**

```
if(data){
   var obj = $.parseJSON(data.trim());
   $.each(obj, function(index, element) {
      $('#divRenderTable').append('<br>'+element.sum+" "+element.description+"   "+element.typecategory.name);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a REST API, how about using RestEasy? It's right for this purpose and can do this automatically.

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html_single/